# 'The message could not be posted to this Wall.' with custom url

Tags: facebook, share

I am trying to incorporate facebook's sharing feature into my site. I am generating the URL, but I get the 'The message could not be posted to this Wall.' error message on my attempt to share. Here is how the url looks like:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=localhost%2F%23%2Fs%2F50f30a31065f90280c000002%2F51b9e958065f90800f000000%2F2
```

My guess is that as I am working on `localhost` facebook tries to validate my URL, because if I replace it with a valid URL I can share it. 
Is there some rule that my link cannot be longer than a specific length?

Comment: I think Facebook bans all URLs that are `localhost` without even trying to validate anything else. Try using a real domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook has to be able to parse the URL you add as parameter, so it cannot be "localhost" but a real page with Open Graph tags on a real server.

See this page for information about the OG tags: http://ogp.me/